# SED cannot open subdirectory

Tags: bash, sed

I have written some code that checks all the folders in the file and matches a regex statement to them however, there is a subfolder in the directory that I want it to enter and also perform the regex on but whenever I run the code it gives me this error

`sed: couldn't edit TestFolder: not a regular file`

I've looked all over S.O and the Internet and can't find anything helpful

I've tried to use code I've found to fix my problem but it isn't helping so I apologise for the potentially hideous code, it's pulled from various sources

```
`pwd = "$PWD"
find $pwd = -print | xargs -0 sed -i "/10.0.0.10/d" !(test.sh)
```

My directory structure follows

`Test
 -one.txt
 -two.txt
TestFolder
 -three.txt`

Answer (score 2):

With GNU find, GNU xargs, and GNU sed:

```
find . -type f -not -name 'test.sh' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '/\<10\.0\.0\.10\>/d'
```

Comment: The original solution worked fine, can you explain the purpose of separating the expression with '\'?

Comment: The original didn't work, you just hadn't noticed it failing, maybe because you hadn't run it against input that would produce the failures. `.` is a regexp metacharacter that matches any character, so `/10.0.0.10/d` would delete lines that contained strings like `10X010Y10`. Escaping the `.`s makes them literal so they only match the intended strings containing `.`s. You also at a minimum need word boundaries so `10\.0\.0\.10` doesn't match against part of `510.0.0.103` or similar. Without seeing your input files idk what other protection against mismatches you might need.

Comment: no need for xargs here, `find . -type f -not -name 'test.sh' -exec sed -i '/\<10\.0\.0\.10\>/d' {} +` will do, for any kind of filename even with spaces, newlines, etc...

Comment: @Sundeep yes, that's true.